# wordpress udpate query not equal to

Tags: wp-query, query

I am trying to write update query where id is not equal to 5

i want output like this but not working.

```
UPDATE `wp_messg` SET `is_read` = 1 WHERE `job_id` = 1 AND `biv_id`!=5

    $id=5;

    $wpdb->update( 
        'wp_messg', 
        array( 
            'is_read' => 1, // string
        ), 
        array( 'job_id' => $id,'biv_id' => $id  ),

        array( 
            '%d',   // value1
        ), 
        array( '%d' ) 
     );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not something `$wpdb->update()` method implements.

If you have custom SQL query that cannot be expressed in API you can run it as is with generic `$wpdb->query()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use `NOT EQUAL` in `$wpdb->update()`. Here look the source code of the `update` method-

```
public function update( $table, $data, $where, $format = null, $where_format = null ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $data ) || ! is_array( $where ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $data = $this->process_fields( $table, $data, $format );
    if ( false === $data ) {
        return false;
    }
    $where = $this->process_fields( $table, $where, $where_format );
    if ( false === $where ) {
        return false;
    }

    $fields = $conditions = $values = array();
    foreach ( $data as $field => $value ) {
        if ( is_null( $value['value'] ) ) {
            $fields[] = "`$field` = NULL";
            continue;
        }

        $fields[] = "`$field` = " . $value['format'];
        $values[] = $value['value'];
    }
    foreach ( $where as $field => $value ) {
        if ( is_null( $value['value'] ) ) {
            $conditions[] = "`$field` IS NULL";
            continue;
        }

        $conditions[] = "`$field` = " . $value['format'];
        $values[] = $value['value'];
    }

    $fields = implode( ', ', $fields );
    $conditions = implode( ' AND ', $conditions );

    $sql = "UPDATE `$table` SET $fields WHERE $conditions";

    $this->check_current_query = false;
    return $this->query( $this->prepare( $sql, $values ) );
}
```

`NOT EQUAL` has not been handled. So it is not possible to use the `NOT EQUAL` on `$wpdb->update()` method.